# How to split a string at a certain point without knowing the place. In python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, api

I am currently pulling in the weather forecast from TFL API. Once extracting the json for 'today's forecast' there are random symbols in the middle of the paragraph - which I think may be formatting from the API.

> This is what is extracted:
>
> ```
> Bank holiday Monday will stay dry with some long sunny spells. Temperatures will remain warm for the time of year.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;PM2.5 particle pollution increased rapidly overnight. Increases began across Essex and spread across south London.  Initial chemical analysis suggests that this is composed mainly of wood burning particles but also with some additional particle pollution from agriculture and traffic. This would be consistent with an air flow from the continent where large bonfires are part of the Easter tradition. This will combine with our local emissions today and &#39;high&#39; PM2.5 is possible.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;The sunny periods, high temperatures and east winds will bring additional ozone precursors allowing for photo-chemical generation of ozone to take place. Therefore &#39;moderate&#39; ozone is likely.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Air pollution should remain &#39;Low&#39; through the forecast period for the following pollutants:&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Nitrogen Dioxide&lt;br/&gt;Sulphur Dioxide.
> ```

The paragraph goes into more detail than necessarily needed, with the first two sentences being all I need. I thought `.split` would be a good idea and running it through a for loop until it reaches the string `"&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;PM2.5"`.
However, I cannot be sure this would be the same string each day, or if the simplified forecast would still only be the first two sentences.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might get around this?

For reference, this is the code I have at the moment, it's not part of anything else yet.

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/AirQuality?"

idno = "1"
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({"$id": idno})

json_data = requests.get(main_api).json()

disclaimer = json_data['disclaimerText']
print("Disclaimer: " + disclaimer)

print()

today_weather = json_data['currentForecast'][0]['forecastText']
print("Today's forecast: " + today_weather.replace("&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;"," "))
```

Comment: Which random symbols do you mean? Also, does the string you read contain `<br>` or `&lt;br&gt;` etc.? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: This is unclear. You say "I cannot be sure this would be the same string each day" but then give no information about what the string that you want to split at could otherwise be. You seem to be asking us how to split data at an unspecified split point. Furthermore, when you say that "or if the simplified forecast would still only be the first two sentences" you seem to be hinting that you need some sort of artificial intelligence which will decide what part of the data you are likely to be interested in.

Comment: @JohnColeman I can't give an example of what it could be as it is updated daily. To be honest, that is what I'm asking (how to split data at an unspecified split point) and the more I think about it, the more I think it can't be done without AI.

Comment: I suspect that it can be done -- but will require some natural language processing. It might not even be all that hard. Vocabulary can probably be used as a criterion with an acceptable error rate. In any event, Python has a rich NLP/machine learning toolkit which should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you clean up the HTML tags and then tokenize the paragraph using NLTK's sentence tokenizer you should be good to go.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

import urllib.parse
import requests
import re

main_api = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/AirQuality?"

idno = "1"
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({"$id": idno})

json_data = requests.get(main_api).json()

disclaimer = json_data['disclaimerText']
print("Disclaimer: " + disclaimer)

print()

# Clean out HTML tags
today_weather_str = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', json_data['currentForecast'][0]['forecastText'])

# Get the first two sentences out of the list
today_weather = ' '.join(sent_tokenize(today_weather_str)[:2])

print("Today's forecast: {}".format(today_weather))
```

Comment: This is definitely a good place to start (+1) but OP's problem description suggests that `[:2]` is not reliable.

Comment: @JohnColeman however the OP is still unclear whether to pick the first two sentences or not, that's a decision he alone can make

Comment: Agreed. I upvoted your answer since it transforms a messy problem into a much cleaner problem. OP will still need to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For you to write a script that is not explicitly coded for each dataset then you would need to find some sort of pattern, if the pattern is that the string you want is always the first two lines then you could use a `for` loop:

```py
data = [line for line in your_variable_here]

data = data[:2]
```

If there seems to be a pattern about what is around the simplified forecast you could also try using a Regular Expression.

But, without more information on what the datasets will look like, I think that is the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

These "random symbols"

```
&lt;br/&gt;
```

are an HTML encoding of

```
<br/>
```

or a new line in HTML, so that looks like a reliable thing to split on:

```
lines = today_weather.split('&lt;br/&gt;')
```

I think it is reasonable to assume that the first line is what you are after:

```
short_forecast = lines[0]
```

Time will tell if that is correct, but you can easily adjust to include more or less.